# solution of inequality with two different methods

Tags: calculus

I have to solve the inequality $$\frac{4}{2-x}\leq1$$ Here is what the solution in my book looks like:$$\frac{4}{2-x}-1\leq0 ~~~~~~~~~~or~~~~~~~~~\frac{2+x}{2-x}\leq0$$ It means either $~~2+x>0~~$ and $~~2-x<0~~$ which implies $~~x>-2~~$ and $~~x>2~~$ so, $~~\textbf{x>2}.$
Or $~~2+x<0~~$ and $~~2-x>0~~$ which implies $~~x<-2~~$ and $~~x<2~~$ so, $~~\textbf{x<-2}.$ Thus the solution set is $$(-\infty, -2)\cup(2, \infty)$$ But isn't $-2$ **included** in the interval? and how do we neglect the equality sign as we have less than or *equal to* sign in the given problem? Or can I solve it like this:$$\frac{4}{2-x}\leq1 ~~~~~\text{or}~~~~4\leq2-x~~~~(\text{multiplied by}~2-x~\text{on both sides for}~2-x\ge0)$$ So we have $$x\leq-2$$ But I don't know what happens if $2-x<0$. The inequality most probably reverses if multiplied by $2-x$. But I can't understand exactly what to do. Please help me with this.

Comment: Clearly, $-2$ satisfies the inequality. If your book states that it does not, then the book is wrong. Your attempt is ok. If $2 - x < 0$, the sign reverses and you can solve it similarly.

Comment: For $2-x<0$, we can write $4\ge2-x$, which would give $x\ge-2$, which isn't correct, I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Question.1: Yes, $-2$ should be included and the correct answer should be $$(-\infty, -2]\cup (2,\infty)$$

For your Question.2: If you multiply $2-x$, you can discuss it in two cases.

Case.(1)

If $2-x>0\Rightarrow x<2~$ (Note you cannot put $2-x=0$ because $x=2$ is not in the domain)

$$4\le 2-x\Rightarrow x\le-2$$

Next you take: $$x<2\cap x\le-2\Rightarrow \boxed{x\le-2}$$

Case.(2)

If $2-x< 0\Rightarrow 2<x~$, when you multiply this term $2-x$ on both sides, since it is negative, you need to flip the inequality sign, which gives:

$$4\ge 2-x\Rightarrow -2\le x$$

Next you take: $$2<x \cap -2\le x \Rightarrow \boxed{2<x}$$

So the final answer will be the union of Case.(1) and Case.(2)

$$(-\infty, -2]\cup (2,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{4}{2-x}\le 1 \implies \frac{4}{2-x}-1  \le 0 \implies \frac{2+x}{2-x}\le 0 \implies \frac{x+2}{x-2}\ge 0 $$
$$\implies \frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{(x-2)^2} \ge 0, x\ne 2 \implies (x+2)(x-2) \ge 0$$
$$\implies x\le -2 ~\text{or}~x >2$$